# How can I have different context path in spring boot for static pages such as .js or .css?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring boot MVC application has,

**ForgotController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "forgot.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView forgotCreds(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    //returns or calls a view 'forgot.jsp' 
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/login
static.contextPath=/static
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
.
.
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
.
.
other config
```

**ViewRegistry.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ViewRegistry implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:build/dist/static/");
    
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource(
        locations = {
                "classpath:/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml"
})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My application that initiates as **localhost:8080/login/forgot.do**, should load static resources from **localhost:8080/static/css/style.css**, but instead I'm getting 404 not found for static resources. And, if I manually check for static content as **localhost:8080/login/static/css/style.css**, it's available. How can i get my spring boot application to serve static pages from '/static' context as **localhost:8080/static/..**?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge last time. First I excluded `/static/**` in the InterceptorRegistry config because the Interceptor felt responsible for it. After the exclusion I had 404 with the static files.

After I made the following entry in application.properties were the static resources loaded.

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
```

Comment: This did not work unfortunately!!